# I'v got a NotSupportedException when convert IQueryable to string[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, type-conversion

I've got a problem with the IQueryable to string[] conversion.

```
 public string[] GetRolesForUser(User user)
    {
        if (!UserExists(user))
            throw new ArgumentException(MissingUser);

        var qry = from x in entities.Roles
               where x.Users.Contains(user)
               select x.RoleName;

        return qry.ToArray(); // At this point I've got a NotSupportedException
    }
```

The exception message:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'SchoolMS.Models.Entities.User'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Please help, how can i fix this? What is the correct way?

(I'm using EF 4.1 with mvc3)

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is in the `x.Users.Contains()`. Would an `x.Users == user` work?

Comment: I tried it but i've got the same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

I'm using many to many relationship between my Users and Roles *(UsersInRoles table provides it)* , that's why my query wasn't suitable for this

I changed the query inside my method and it's working fine..

```
public string[] GetRolesForUser(User user)
{
    if (!UserExists(user))
        throw new ArgumentException(MissingUser);

    var qry = entities.Users
        .Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleName));

    return qry.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that entity framework can't create a constant for the `user` variable in your query. One solution could be to create a join manually rather than use `Contains`:

```
var qry =   from x in entities.Roles
            join Users u on u.RoleId = x.Id
            where u.Id = user.Id
            select x.RoleName
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to write

```
var qry = from x in entities.Roles
  where x.Users.Select(u => u.Id).Contains(user.Id)
  select x.RoleName;
```

So it would be a primitive type, as requested.